# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar una clase Java creada y compilada desde Netbeans por la consola de comandos?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un proyecto en `Netbeans 8.1` y `Java 1.8.0_65` de 64 bits. Desde el IDE la ejecución es correcta pero cuando intento ejecutar el mismo programa desde la consola CMD recibo el típico mensaje:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

Ahora me ubico en la carpeta `build` que genera Netbeans donde se encuentran mis clases compiladas y en ella creo una nueva clase en el notepad lo compilo y ejecuto y funciona bien. Sin embargo la clase que hago desde Netbeans no logro ejecutar.

Adjunto la pantalla con la ubicación del proyecto y los intentos de ejecutar la clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora cuando ejecuto la clase `Hello` obtengo un saludo, pero al ejecutar `StdRandom` me da el error que dice. Añado que también intenté compilar manualmente la clase `StdRandom` la cual fue exitosa y luego de su ejecución falló con el error arriba mencionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado la definición de la clase StdRandom

```
package fmw.java.com.ceva.algorithms;

import java.util.Random;

public final class StdRandom 
{
    private static Random random;
    private static long seed;

    static
    {
        seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        random = new Random(seed);
    }

    private StdRandom()
    {}

    public static void setSeed(long s)
    {
        seed = s;
        random = new Random(seed);
    }

    public static long getSeed()
    {
        return seed;
    }

    public static double uniforme()
    {
        return random.nextDouble();
    }

    public static int uniforme(int n)
    {
        if(n == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parametro debe ser positivo");
        }
        return random.nextInt(n);
    }

    public static void shuffle(Object[] a) {
        if (a == null) throw new NullPointerException("argument array is null");
        int n = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = i + uniforme(n-i);     // between i and n-1
            Object temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[r];
            a[r] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 5;
        System.out.println("seed: " + StdRandom.getSeed());
        String[] a = "A B C D E F".split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%2d "  , uniforme(100));
            StdRandom.shuffle(a);
            for (String s : a)
                System.out.print(s);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Bueno, el joven preguntó ¿porqué no puede ejecutar la clase?

Mencionar que copié la clase y cambié el nombre del paquete (por copyright del autor ahahah)

Ok. Vamos a resumir y a explicar porqué.
Cuando se trabaja con IDE's, una de las cosas que el IDE trabaja por nosotros es el tema del `classpath`, que en pocas palabras es el lugar desde donde se empieza la búsqueda de clases que podría necesitar nuestra clase en cuestión, es decir; sus dependencias (si las tiene).

Para este caso particular no tenemos una dependencia como tal, tenemos un `import java.util.Random;` pero ello forma parte del JSE, así que no hay problema.

El problema aquí es la sentencia `package`. Al definir tu clase en un paquete, eso incluye ajustes de classpath que al trabajar con Netbeans; eran asumidos por él.

Como se trabajó en un IDE, la estructura de directorios y sentencia `package` van a estar correctas, en caso de que no sea un IDE y lo trabajamos a mano, hay que asegurarse de ello.

Netbeans ubica los compilados en /build/classes; Eclipse los coloca en target/classes. Entonces puede que quieras usar el compilado o volver a compilar. Supongamos que lo compilamos otra vez, entonces vamos a tener `.java` y `.class` lado a lado.

Si se intenta ejecutar la clase simplemente con `java StdRamdon` el error lanzado será el siguiente:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StdRandom (wrong name: com/java/edu/ropher/algorithms/StdRandom)`

**¿Porqué?**

Porque nuestra clase no se llama `StdRamdom`, se llama `com.java.edu.ropher.algorithms.StdRandom`, que es lo que llamamos `qualified name`

Entonces, ejecutémosla con su nombre completo!

```
java com.java.edu.ropher.algotithms.StdRandom
```

Pero tampoco vá, ahora nos dice esto

```
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal com.java.edu.ropher.algotithms.StdRandom
```

**¿Porqué?**

Porque, realmente la JVM no sabe en donde se encuentra nuestra clase, necesita del classpath para poder ubicarla, pero **¿porqué?** porque hemos definido nuestra clase en un paquete. De no haberlo hecho, todo habría sido mágico.

Pero bueno, entonces hagámosle con el classpath

```
java -classpath D:\ROSPENA\Escritorio\Test com.java.edu.ropher.algorithms.StdRandom
```

Y Voilaaa!!

```
seed: 1454604765916
99 DAEFCB
47 AECDFB
66 ADEFBC
13 ECAFDB
62 CEBAFD
```

**Update**

Quizá me faltó mencionarlo, ¿porque el classpath que usé es `D:\ROSPENA\Escritorio\Test`. Porque `Test` es la carpeta raíz que contiene los directorios del paquete (y está ubicada en mi Escritorio)

`Test->com->java->edu->ropher->algorithms`

y es partir de allí desde donde debe iniciar la búsqueda de componentes.

Lo que nos hacía falta era el classpath, pero no sólo eso ... ya sabemos **porqué**

Un saludo y espero que se haya entendido.

Comment: Muchas gracias Rosendo, claro como el agua.

Comment: Siempre a la orden, saludos!

Answer (score 6):

Según lo que veo en la consola, tu clase debe lucir aproximadamente así:

```
package fmw.java.com.ceva.algorithms;

//sentencias import, si es que hay...

public class StdRandom {
    //contenido de la clase...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //contenido del método main...
    }
}
```

Y tú te ubicas en la siguiente ruta:

> C:\Users\barcvilla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CevaFmw\build\classes\fmw\java\com\ceva\algorithms

Al ejecutar el comando `dir` te listará los archivos, por lo cual encontramos el compilado `StdRandom.class`

Cuando ejecutas una clase Java ya compilada, debes estar en una ruta donde puedas encontrar a la clase utilizando su nombre completo. El nombre completo de una clase es:

> `<nombre del paquete>` + `<nombre de la clase>`

Para este caso, sería: `fmw.java.com.ceva.algorithms.StdRandom`

Entonces, para ejecutar esta clase:

1. Deberías al menos situarte por encima de la carpeta com. Esto es, desde tu consola, en la carpeta `C:\Users\barcvilla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CevaFmw\build\classes\`
2. Ejecutar el comando `java <nombre completo de clase>`. Para que el anterior funcione, quizás sea necesario agregar el classpath o lugar donde se encuentran las clases. Para efecto de este escenario, sería la misma carpeta, o sea `.`

En comandos:

```
> cd C:\Users\barcvilla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CevaFmw\build\classes\
> java -cp . fmw.java.com.ceva.algorithms.StdRandom
```

Esto es, asumiendo que no hay ninguna dependencia externa como librerías adicionales que deberían ser agregadas al classpath.

Answer (score 2):

como es un paquete el cual contiene la clase debes de ejecutar el .class desde una dirección atrás de donde comienza la ruta del paquete en este caso puedes ejecutar el comando `java Clase` en la direccion:

```
C:\Users\barcvilla\Documents\NetBeansProyects\CevaFmw\build\clases> java fmw\java\com\ceva\algorithms\ StdRandom;
```

esto es si no sabes manejar el comando -cp para evitarte este tipo de situaciones, de manejo de clases en diferentes carpetas como lo hace NetBeans. De hecho el error lo marca como si no se hubiese compilado el .java, es por eso

Answer (score 1):

Intenta especificar el espacio de nombres en el comando (Es decir el `"fully qualified name"`)

```
java packageName.StdRandom
```

Revisa tambien que el metodo Main contiene la firma apropiada (los args)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: intento la siguiente instruccion; java fmw.java.com.ceva.algorithms.StdRandom me lanza el error no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal

Comment: Puedes porfavor incluir la clase en cuestion, al menos que contenga el metodo Main

Comment: al colocarme en la ruta C:\Users\barcvilla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CevaFmw\build\classes y ejecutar desde ahi la clase, recien funcionó. Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

También quise hacer lo mismo.
Lo que hice fue:

- Copiar los .java en otra carpeta.
- Comentar la linea de codigo que dice "package 'nombreDePackage'".
- Compilé el .java que contiene la clase main.
- Ejecuté con el comando java y listo, funcionó