# No puedo ejecutar una clase Java compilada desde Eclipse con librerías externas por la terminal?

Tags: java

En referencia a: [¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar una clase Java creada y compilada desde Netbeans por la consola de comandos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3547/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-ejecutar-una-clase-java-creada-y-compilada-desde-netbeans-por/33175#33175)

Disculpen, pero ¿Qué hacer cuando necesitas usar una librería como `jgroups-3.6.11.Final.jar` para compilar la clase? Porque seguí los pasos de *[Rosendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/191/rosendo-ropher)*, pero sigue dándome error. Tal vez porque previamente ejecuté:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Paul\Downloads\jgroups-3.6.11.Final.jar;%CLASSPATH%;.;
```

Comment: usa el comando  javac

Answer (score 0):

Primero compila tu proyecto:

```
javac clasePrincipal.java
```

Despues utiliza el siguiente comando en caso de que sea linux:

```
java -cp $dir:lib_ext.jar clasePrincipal
```

Para Windows utiliza:

```
java -cp $dir;lib_ext.jar clasePrincipal
```

Donde:

> $dir es la ruta donde se encuentra la librería
>
> lib_ext es el nombre de tu librería
>
> clasePrincipal es la clase donde esta el método main